# What exactly is the meaning of "No doping" sign on a drug package?

Tags: medications, substance-abuse

I noticed a "No doping" sign on the back of a pack of Dopamine HCl ampoules. It looks like this:
[image]

I was wondering what is the purpose of this sign. I am guessing that it means that the drug should not be abused, but why is it on the package? Who is it aimed at? Since these are amouples for infusion, they should not be accessible to someone who is not a medical professional, and medical professionals are less likely to abuse it (I hope).

And even if someone does get their hands on the drugs with the intention to abuse it, this sign would surely not stop them...

So, is this really what's behind this sign, or did I miss something?

Comment: Your link to the image is broken.

Comment: Managed to upload the image, thanks.

Comment: "Doping" usually refers to use of banned substances in athletics, rather than recreational abuse. Is it possible this mark is really the logo or mark of some anti-doping org? I'm not aware of dopamine being on a banned substance list, but if it is the presence of this logo could be to ensure athletes and their physicians/trainers are aware the substance is not allowed (which also makes an athlete's defense that they didn't know they took something banned).

Comment: The sign could warn that consuming this medicament by athletes can be detected as doping or could inform about the opposite, that it is safe for athletes because it is not banned and test can't miss it with a banned product. Since dopamine doesn't seem to be banned, I would guess the latter.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. So no one was able to find any official explanation or reference for the meaning of this logo? Perhaps I'll try to contact the manufacturer. If I'll find something, I'll post it here.